# What difference does it make if I declare and access a class' property directly?

Tags: java, class, scope

```
public class MyData {
    public String id_number,first_name,last_name,age,level;
    public MyData(String raw_string){
        String[] parameters = raw_string.split(",");
        for(int x = 1;x<parameters.length;x++){
            String[] key_val = parameters[x].split("=");
            if(key_val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ID")){
                id_number = key_val[1];
            }
            if(key_val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("FN")){
                first_name = key_val[1];
            }
            if(key_val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("LN")){
                last_name = key_val[1];
            }
            if(key_val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("AG")){
                age = key_val[1];
            }
            if(key_val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("LV")){
                level = key_val[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I usually declare classes like the one above on my school projects, and now I have been programming for real world applications,
I practiced using the get - set approach on the understanding that it provides control only for the class itself.

From how I understood it, declaring class properties like the one above can result in unexpected change in value simply by `MyData.name = "Here's a new name for me.";`

Being lazy, I tend to return to that practice because typing `getName();` and `setName("This is my name");` is too time consuming (I'm aware IDE's can speed things up but still...)

Not to mention the time it takes to writing two functions (get and set, plus a `clear()` if necessary) for each property.
So question is, do I really need to comply with the get - set approach?

PS: Please rephrase my question to reflect the proper programming terminologies (i did not really pay attention to class that much).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question revolves around good programming style, and depending on how many people read this question, you're going to get quite a few very angry responses that are adamant that even asking this question is a sin. The short answer is that of [code encapsulation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

You're writing extremely small programs for your classes and you're writing them to a set of criteria that is well known and precisely defined at the beginning of the assignment and never changes. Unfortunately, few programs written in the real world have either of these properties. They are large programs with a design that isn't truly finished until the program is (hint, that's never), and they solve problems which aren't well understood and continually change.

In light of these challenges, and many more I haven't mentioned, (the biggest result of which is that you will change many parts of your code many times once you write them) programmers have come up with a set of practices that make programming more tolerable. Among the most important things you can do is to isolate changes in your programs. This means when you change something in one part of your system, it should involve as few changes as possible to other parts of your system.

Encapsulation is one way to help you achieve this isolation of changes. If you decide to change something big about the MyData class, you have to change every single class that uses MyData. For instance, say you decide that MyData should hold much more than the 5 fields you've defined, or that the fields MyData stores should dynamically change at runtime. I would do this by giving MyData a private HashMap that holds all your strings, which can then be accessed by key.

In this situation, if you had used getFirstName(), getLastName(), etc, the other classes that use MyData would have no idea anything changed, and would go along their business. But the way you've done things, by exposing data, every single one of them would have to be modified, turning a few minutes of work into a days worth or more. (And trust me, small utilities like this usually end up being used in a LOT of places.)

Also, try not to get stuck on the example I've given you. There are at least 5 other examples I can think of so saying this example would never happen to you, or finding a different way to solve it, is not only missing the point, it's completely missing the point.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends with what you mean by "need". If you want to end up with any degree of encapsulation, you shouldn't be exposing public fields. If you want the ability to change the implementation details of how data is stored, or validate any values set on the field, etc - then you need to use properties.

The details of the storage are *implementation* details. They shouldn't affect a caller. If you want to change the names of private variables between versions, that's absolutely fine. If you want to change from storing (say) the start and end points of a view onto a collection to storing the start and count, that's fine - you can do all of that without breaking the public API.

Of course there's much more to encapsulation than *just* using properties instead of public fields, but it's a fundamental starting point IMO.

I would *strongly* urge you to use properties.

Comment: @Nivas: Yes: getFoo() and setFoo() is commonly known as a property called foo.

Answer (score 0):

I would completely agree with other answers. But the abundance of great refactoring-enabled IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ will allow you to easily change field-accessed properties to getter/setter access (and plenty more).

If you are writing a program that is going to be used by other developers (say, using version control like CVS) then it would be best to stick to writing nicely encapsulated getter/setter style classes to avoid unnecessary refactoring (causing lots for silly merge conflicts) in advance.

If you are going to be working on your own for a while before publishing your changes and just want to get things done quickly, then use style that makes your more productive. You will likely refactor your program a million times before actually making it available to others, so might as well do it on the final version to save you some time. But that's a question of programming style.